# Suggest OAuth flow(grant type) or approach for below requirement

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

CompanyA is integrating with CompanyB where CompanyA's users will be buying devices of CompanyB.

CompanyA wants to show user's device(CompanyB) details on their app by calling

CompanyB's API on each user login.

CompanyA user is authenticated on CompanyA IAM.

CompanyA has to call register device when user tries to add an device first time.

Help me to identify the flow which i can use to query particular loggedin user's device only.

Do i need to create duplicate user account on CompanyB's IAM?

If i use client credential flow for API to API call, access token given by CompanyB is only provides access for API calls but it does not tell that on behalf of correct user only call is invoked.

Assume that CompanyA uses IdentityServer or any other provider as IAM and CompanyB uses Azure AD B2C.

Any other approach?

Please see below diagram,

[image: CompanyA and CompanyB interaction]

Comment: One question for that is how does the company B service know that the user from company A is the same user that they have on file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
First time, they will have to call an CompanyB's API to register an device. This does device and user mapping. I will update this point on post

Comment: Alright, so CompanyB API could store the calling user's object id and tenant id and attach the device to them. A multi-tenant API could work then.

Comment: @juunas, Thanks. Could you please explain multi-tenant API solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by making the Company B API multi-tenant in their Azure AD.
There are other options surely, this is just the first one that came to my mind.

[Overview of the multi-tenant pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview)

You would have to do admin consent on it to get the API's service principal in your Azure AD tenant.
The Company B API can give you an endpoint for doing this, redirecting you with the proper parameters to the authorization endpoint. [How to send a sign-in request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-the-sign-in-request)

After doing this, you should be able to then require permissions on the API from Company A API in your tenant (configured in Azure AD).
[Configure a client application to access web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications#configure-a-client-application-to-access-web-apis)

After doing those things, your API should be able to use On-Behalf-Of grant flow to get an access token for Company B API.
[Using Azure AD On-Behalf-Of flow in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 API](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core)

Company B API must be configured to accept access tokens from another issuer than their Azure AD of course.
In general multi-tenant scenarios, the issuer validation is commonly turned off.
If Company B wishes to have control over this, currently they will have to explicitly list the valid issuers.
Issuer values look like this: `https://sts.windows.net/31537af4-6d77-4bb9-a681-d2394888ea26/`, the GUID is your Azure AD tenant id.

The Company B API can extract the tenant id and user object id from the access token, and authorize the user to resources based on them.

Comment: This could be answer when CompanyA is also using Azure AD as IAM. In this case, let us assume CompanyA uses different IAM provider for example Identityserver and CompanyB uses Azure AD B2C. It will be helpful if approach works independent of CompanyA IAM provider.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the AWS side and looks like they have something that could meet the requirements

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_federated-users.html

Was wondering if something like this exists in Azure.