# Create access token from azure AD using assertion flow for access token received from Identity server

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Requirement:
CompanyA(uses Identity server and has user store) Web API wants to call CompanyB(uses Azure AD and does not have user store) web API with user identity in the token. Becuase CompanyB has to provide user's resource on the api.
CompanyA web api called from client of companyA using access token which has user identity in that.

Please check this question for more clarity on requirement,
[Requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582103/suggest-oauth-flowgrant-type-or-approach-for-below-requirement)

Is it possible to get new access token from azure ad to call CompanyB web api from companyA web api by using the token from which it is called?

below are my references,

https://leastprivilege.com/2013/12/23/advanced-oauth2-assertion-flow-why/

https://leastprivilege.com/2013/12/23/advanced-oauth2-assertion-flow-how/
[Here token recieved from Microsoft is validated and given new token from IdentityServer. But i need reverse of it]

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7521

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523#section-2.2

Comment: I don't think an API which uses another IdP can use the token to exchange it for an Azure AD access token. Probably the API has to use client credentials flow to get an access token as the app itself with no use context.